# Remove audio streams from multiple videos at once

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-scripting

I use `ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -map -0:a:2 -c copy output` to remove audio stream from a signle video. How can i apply this command to more than one video without duplicating the command. I am on windows.

Answer (score -1):

How to remove audio stream from multible videos at once:

1- Lacate the file within which the videos you want to edit
2- make a new file named 'edit'
3- open powershell
4- write cmd and open
5- write the following command:

```
   for %i in (*.avi) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -map 0 -map -0:a:0 -c copy ./edit/"%~ni.avi"
```

change the second zero denoting the unwanted audio stream (e.g., if the unwanted stream is no.3, will be 0:a:2)
change the video type (.avi) to the respective type